# Highcharts - change AlternateGridColor when exporting using old look exporting script

Tags: highcharts

Using Highcharts v3.0.2 and the latest exporting module I'm able to change AlternateGridColor in exporting using exporting: ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fudoki22/FcnwT/))

```
{  xAxis : { alternateGridColor: #ffffff }   }
```

When rendered out as .png alternateGridColor is white. I've a requirement to keep the Highcharts 2 export / download buttons and using the exporting-old-look.js file

https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/js/modules/exporting-old-look.src.js

does this nicely, but adding this script stops the exporting alternateGridColor from being used. Has anyone got around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it looks like a problem with chartOptions for xAxis parameter. Because it should be

```
exporting:{
    chartOptions:{
        xAxis:{
           //...
        }
    }
}
```

I reported it here https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2022